# How do I get my gamble command to work? Or is there another way to write one?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 8, commands.BucketType.user)
async def bet(self, ctx, amount=0):
  if amount == 0:
    await ctx.send("Please enter a valid amount you want to bet!")
  else:
    db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT money FROM main WHERE member_id = {ctx.message.author.id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
      sql = ("INSERT INTO main(member_id, money, user, dildo, vibrator, butt_plug, rope, ball_gags, earth,star_blaster, purple_guy, bomb, gun, sword, halberd) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")
      val = (ctx.message.author.id, 250, ctx.message.author.name, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
      cursor.execute(sql, val)
      await ctx.send("Because you didn't have an account, I just made one for you! Use the command again to see your money.")
      db.commit()
    elif amount > int(result[0]):
      await ctx.send("You don't have the money for this!")
    elif amount > 1:
      randomchoice = randint(1, 2)
      if randomchoice == 2:
        amountbad = int(result[0]) - amount
        sql = (cursor.execute("UPDATE main SET money = ? WHERE member_id = ?"))
        val = (amountbad, ctx.message.author.id)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit
        await ctx.send(f"Sorry, you lost {amount}")
      elif randomchoice == 1:
        amountgood = int(result[0]) + (amount * 2)
        resultgood = amount * 2
        sql = (cursor.execute("UPDATE main SET money = ? WHERE member_id = ?"))
        val = (amountgood, ctx.message.author.id)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit
        await ctx.send(f"Woohoo! You just won ${resultgood}!")
      elif amount > 1000:
        randomchoice2 = randint(1, 3)
        if randomchoice2 == 1:
          amountgood1 = int(result[0]) + (amount * 2)
          resultgood1 = amount * 2
          sql = (cursor.execute("UPDATE main SET money = ? WHERE member_id = ?"))
          val = (amountgood1, ctx.message.author.id)
          cursor.execute(sql, val)
          db.commit
          await ctx.send(f"Woohoo! You just won ${resultgood1}!")
        else:
          amountbad1 = int(result[0]) - amount
          sql = (cursor.execute("UPDATE main SET money = ? WHERE member_id = ?"))
          val = (amountbad1, ctx.message.author.id)
          cursor.execute(sql, val)
          db.commit
          await ctx.send(f"Sorry, you lost {amount}")
      elif amount > 10000:
        randomchoice3 = randint(1, 5)
        if randomchoice3 == 1:
          amountgood2 = int(result[0]) + (amount * 2)
          resultgood2 = amount * 2
          sql = (cursor.execute("UPDATE main SET money = ? WHERE member_id = ?"))
          val = (amountgood2, ctx.message.author.id)
          cursor.execute(sql, val)
          db.commit
          await ctx.send(f"Woohoo! You just won ${resultgood2}!")
        else:
          amountbad2 = int(result[0]) - amount
          sql = (cursor.execute("UPDATE main SET money = ? WHERE member_id = ?"))
          val = (amountbad2, ctx.message.author.id)
          cursor.execute(sql, val)
          db.commit
          await ctx.send(f"Sorry, you lost {amount}")
      elif amount > 100000:
        randomchoice4 = randint(1, 7)
        if randomchoice4 == 1:
          amountgood3 = int(result[0]) + (amount * 2)
          resultgood3 = amount * 2
          sql = (cursor.execute("UPDATE main SET money = ? WHERE member_id = ?"))
          val = (amountgood3, ctx.message.author.id)
          cursor.execute(sql, val)
          db.commit
          await ctx.send(f"Woohoo! You just won ${resultgood3}!")
        else:
          amountbad3 = int(result[0]) - amount
          sql = (cursor.execute("UPDATE main SET money = ? WHERE member_id = ?"))
          val = (amountbad3, ctx.message.author.id)
          cursor.execute(sql, val)
          db.commit
          await ctx.send(f"Sorry, you lost {amount}")
      else:
        if amount > 100001:
          randomchoice4 = randint(1, 30)
        if randomchoice4 == 1:
          amountgood3 = int(result[0]) + (amount * 2)
          resultgood3 = amount * 2
          sql = (cursor.execute("UPDATE main SET money = ? WHERE member_id = ?"))
          val = (amountgood3, ctx.message.author.id)
          cursor.execute(sql, val)
          db.commit
          await ctx.send(f"Woohoo! You just won ${resultgood3}!")
        else:
          amountbad3 = int(result[0]) - amount
          sql = (cursor.execute("UPDATE main SET money = ? WHERE member_id = ?"))
          val = (amountbad3, ctx.message.author.id)
          cursor.execute(sql, val)
          db.commit
          await ctx.send(f"Sorry, you lost {amount}")
          cursor.close
          db.close
```

The command stops working am assuming at "elif amount > 1" because nothing else happens after that point. if there's any other way I could write this gamble command then please send it to me, or maybe this has an easy fix once again, please help me! I'm tried on this for a while and I can't find a way for this to work...

Comment: well amount will be a string, so you should cast it to an integer.

Comment: Changed all of the amount into an int an still nothing.